# How to change default iOS back behavior to avoid going back and forth between two views?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, navigation

I have an app whose navigation tree is described on the attached image. Basically, I have two main screens (Home and Profile), both of which can access the settings screen. On that settings screen I can go to many different specific setting screens to change. Once the user accepts the changes in any of those screens, it goes back to the main settings screen.

[image: App Navigation]
The expected behavior of the back button is the following:

- From the Settings screen, go back to Home or Profile, depending how the user got to the settings screen in the first place.
- From any of the specific `S{x}` screens it should go back to the main Settings screen.

I'm currently using the default back behavior, but I have issues on the following case:

```
Home -> Settings -> S1 -> Settings -> S1 -> Settings
```

If the user presses the Back button, I would like it to go back to the Home screen, but it goes back to S1, and then back to Settings, and then back to S1 and so on, depending on how many times I entered the S1 screen.

How can I make the Settings view to "remember" to which screen it should go back to?

Comment: `UINavigationController` is your friend.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller?  What do you mean by "default back behaviour"?  It sounds like when you go back it is pushing the settings screen onto the stack instead of popping the current view controller off the stack.

Comment: By "default back behavior" I mean I'm just calling `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`.

Should all my views use `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController`?

Comment: `UINavigationController` is not an alternative to `UIViewController`.  It's a container view controller that manages your other view controllers.  Read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) and see my answer for an overview of what you should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manage your view controller hierarchy manually.  Use `UINavigationController`, this is what it is designed for.  When you need to go from your home screen to your settings screen, instantiate your settings view controller and push it onto the stack.  When you need to go from your settings screen to S1, instantiate your S1 controller and push it onto the stack.  When you need to come back out from S1 to your settings screen, pop it off the stack.  When you need to come back out from your settings screen to your home screen, pop it off the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use a stack here. Each time you navigate to a new page without using the back button, push the old page onto the stack. Each time you use the back button, pop the last-added page off the stack. This way you can 'remember' which page to go back to as you say :) Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I gave the correct answer to Jim because he pointed me in the right direction of using the `UINavigationController`. But the stack approach seems to be correct just as you said.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted!